# Resolve this system of linear equations in Z/Z7 and write 8 possible solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x_1  &+&2x_2&+&3x_5&&&&&=& 3;\\
2x_1 &+&4x_2&+&3x_3&+&6x_4&+&x_5 &=& 5;\\
3x_1 &+&6x_2&+&2x_3&+&4x_4&+&x_5 &=& 6;\\
4x_1 &+&x_2&+&3x_3&+&6x_4&&&=&4.
\end{array}
\right.
$

I transformed this matrix in normal form, then i calculated 49 possible solutions. But how can I write down 8 of 49 of this possible solutions?

Comment: I don't know how to use it for big parenthesis

Comment: Did you check the link [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ?  Also by x1 do you mean $x_1$ (\$x_1\$)?

Comment: Yeah i read that link. Yes for x1 i mean that.

Comment: I still can't do the big parenthesis but now I edited numbers and symbols